# insert a word in lines and save the files using Python

Tags: python

I Have files in a directory that have many lines like this

```
cd /oasis/projects/nsf/ets100/
oconv /oasis/projects/nsf/ets100/rla
```

I would like to insert the word "sky/" so the second line reads like this

```
oconv /oasis/projects/nsf/sky/ets100/rla
```

What is the best way to do this?

I know that the beginning of the code will be something like this:

```
path = r"c:\test"
    for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as fRead:
                if line.startswith("oconv"):
```

Comment: how do you know where to insert 'sky'  in the string? is it always before the 2nd last folder in the path? does the path always start with '/oasis/projects/nsf/'?

Comment: use os.path.split, check docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Comment: @richflow yes, the path always starts with '/oasis/projects/nsf/'

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
def replace_line(file):
   with open(os.path.abspath(file), 'r') as file_obj:
       data = file_obj.readlines()
   for index, lines in enumerate(data):
       if lines.startswith('oconv'):
          data[index] = lines.replace('/nsf/', '/nsf/sky/')
   with open(os.path.abspath(file), 'w') as file_obj:
       file_obj.writelines(data)


path = r"c:\test"
    for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            replace_line(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to update the string:

```
import os
import re

path = r"c:\test"
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk('test'):
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r+') as fh: #open the file with 'r+' to read and write
            content = fh.read()
            new_content = re.sub(r'oconv \/oasis\/projects\/nsf\/(.*)', r'oconv /oasis/projects/nsf/sky/\1', content) #replace strings in file
            fh.seek(0)
            fh.truncate()
            fh.write(new_content)
```